# Is there a way to sort the values of a DataStructure (Key/Value pairs) by first extracting the values (int) to an array, and performing a MergeSort?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, insert, recursive-datastructures

I want to simulate an interview scheduler, where the names with the highest scores are called first. It is my priority to make sure I apply the mergeSort algorithm somehow to this implementation.
What I have in mind is to copy the **values,** of type int, in the Data Structure to an array, perform the sort on the array, and put it back into the data structure.

My challenge is having to insert the data back into the Data Structure with the numbers having their respective (initial) names being retained as the **keys.**

I tried using a switch statement to add the names manually with the values where the element in an array is a certain value:

`int[] ints = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}; switch (ints) { case 5: Applicants.Add("Some name", 5); break; default: }`

But I can't add the number 5 because I get an error (cannot implicitely convert type int[] to int)

How else can I copy these elements to the values of a DataStructure, having the names matching their scores?

Comment: Sort the entire structure based on your key, instead of create another array.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods to do this, but if you want to create an array from the values of your Key-Value Data Structure, you can also try the following:

- Instead of creating an integer array, create a class that contains name and score
- [Java perspective] -- This class should implement Comparable to sort the class objects in order
- Once the object array is sorted [in-built method or your merge sort], the sorted array will have both Name and score in the decreasing order you want
- From this ordered sorted array you can insert both key and values to the Data structure

-----Code

```
static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
        private String name;
        private int score;

        public Pair(String name, int score) {
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair o) {
            return o.score - this.score;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair[] array = new Pair[4];
        array[0] = new Pair("A", 3);
        array[1] = new Pair("B", 1);
        array[2] = new Pair("C", 5);
        array[3] = new Pair("D", 2);
        Arrays.sort(array);

        for (Pair p : array) {
            System.out.println(p.name + "--" + p.score);
        }
    }
```

-----Output-----

```
C--5
A--3
D--2
B--1
```

Comment: It worked! but.. I'm having an issue with deriving the score from the  Array 'array'. I have to do that before I can sort it. Doing a MergeSort as it is with the Names there seems more unlikely to me.

Comment: can you share the link for the code?

Comment: here: https://github.com/Jaeson-gram/InterviewSchedule